# echo not printing \033 correctly in pipeline started by os.system()

Tags: python, bash, echo, ansi-colors

In bash (as started by Python), I want to print this string `\033[31m` so that I can use a pipe `|` operator after it, followed by a command to copy that string to the clipboard. This means that in practice, I'm trying to run something like:

```py
os.system('echo \\033[31m | xsel -ib')
```

...but the `xsel -ib` part is working fine, so this question is focused specifically on the behavior of `echo`.

---

Most of my attempts have been similar to:

```
echo -e \\033[31m
```

I have tried it with single quotes, double quotes, no quotes, removing the `-e` flag, etc. The closest I got was:

```
echo -n "\\ 033[31m"
```

which prints this string `\ 033[31m`

I don't want that space between `\` and `0`

`-n` flag is used to not append a new line after the printed string

---

I use Ubuntu 20.04, and `xsel` is a selection and clipboard manipulation tool for the X11 Window System (which Ubuntu 20.04 uses).

Comment: `removing the -e flag` You sure you did try that? `echo \\033[31m` prints `\033[31m`. To be absolutely clear, you _want_ to copy `\033` _characters_, not `0x1b` _byte_? `The closest I got was:` soooooo remove the space???

Comment: It works in bash, I guess the problem was that I was running it in fish shell (not bash shell)

Comment: `is from a python script` So, when you do `print('echo \\033[0m')` from python, what is printed out?

Comment: it print out `echo \033[0m`

Comment: I think the real question is: what are you ultimately trying to achieve with this?

Comment: That string, in interpreted form, is a terminal escape sequence. If you "print" that to a terminal the terminal itself will interpret it and won't show you any characters. It may, in fact, be printing to your terminal. You just won't see it as characters.

Comment: Note that whether `echo` processes escape sequences by default is unspecified by the POSIX sh standard, which recommends using `printf` instead for any strings including them. That is to say, **the correct behavior of `echo \\033[31m` is completely unspecified when executed by a shell**.

Comment: See the APPLICATION USAGE section of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html; quoting the first line here, with emphasis added: *It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both -n (as the first argument) **and escape sequences** are omitted*. The value you're trying to `echo` includes an escape sequence.

Comment: Also, `system()` uses `sh`, not your regular shell (be it bash/fish/whatever).

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a bit more clear (moving content out of distinct "update" sections into the body itself). See [Why is writing an "update" section in a SO question frowned on?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368283/why-is-writing-an-update-section-in-an-so-question-frowned-upon) on [meta]. Similarly, [Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is the wrong tool for the job. It's a shell builtin, and one for which the POSIX sh standard explicitly does not guarantee portable behavior for when escape sequences (such as `\033`) are present. `system()` starts `/bin/sh` instead of bash, so POSIX behavior -- not that of your regular interactive shell -- is expected.

Use `subprocess.run()` instead of `os.system()`, and you don't need `echo` in the first place.

If you want to put an escape sequence into the clipboard (so not `\033` but instead the ESC key that this gets converted to by an `echo` with XSI extensions to POSIX):

```py
# to store \033 as a single escape character, use a regular Python bytestring
subprocess.run(['xsel', '-ib'], input=b'\033[31m')
```

If you want to put the literal text without being interpreted (so there's an actual backslash and an actual zero), use a raw bytestring instead:

```py
# to store \033 as four separate characters, use a raw string
subprocess.run(['xsel', '-ib'], input=rb'\033[31m')
```

For a more detailed description of why `echo` causes problems in this context, see the excellent answer by Stephane to the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

---

If you for some reason *do* want to keep using a shell pipeline, switch to `printf` instead:

```py
# to store \033 as four separate characters, use %s
subprocess.run(r''' printf '%s\n' '\033[31m' | xsel -ib ''', shell=True)
```

```py
# to store \033 as a single escape character, use %b
subprocess.run(r''' printf '%b\n' '\033[31m' | xsel -ib ''', shell=True)
```

Comment: The second command worked, but first one (with `echo`) didn't work, and threw the error below 
```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```
I use Python 3.8.8
I guess I am going to use the second one (the one using `printf`.) Thanks a lot

Comment: @H.B., you can change to `''` to `b''` and `r''` to `rb''` to avoid that error. Just a minute and I'll try to reproduce it, and edit the answer to incorporate a fix if I can.

Comment: @H.B., ...reproduced the issue, edited accordingly to fix; thank you for the heads up.